# Implementing pipe command in c++

Tags: c++, terminal, pipe

I am trying to make a terminal that has a native support to pipe commands.
I have tried to implement this but whenever I try to execute a pipe command it is executed over and over again until my pc crashes - probably some memory but I can't backtrack to exactly what's causing it.

*This Question is a part of an academic assignment*

Before I show the implementation of this command, I am going to explain what are the functions that I use inside the pipes implementation:
`_parseCommandLine` - takes in a command char* and some empty array args - for each argument it dynamically allocates space for it inside the args array and finally the function returns the number of arguments.

`_isBackgroundComamnd` and `_removeBackgroundSign` seems pretty self explanatory.

`_clear_command` simply frees the array of arguments and the command itself.

If you need clarifications on more functions let me know.

Here's my implementation

```
void PipeCommand::execute(){
  char* args1[COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH];
  char* args2[COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH];
  char* command1 = (char*)malloc(COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH);
  char* command2 = (char*)malloc(COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH);
  char* command1_print = (char*)malloc(COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH);
  char* command2_print = (char*)malloc(COMMAND_ARGS_MAX_LENGTH);
  unsigned int cmd_sep_out = string(this->command).find("|");
  unsigned int cmd_sep_err = string(this->command).find("|&");

  strcpy(command1, string(this->command).substr(0, cmd_sep_out).c_str());
  if(cmd_sep_err != string::npos){
    strcpy(command2, string(this->command).substr(cmd_sep_err + 1).c_str());
  } else{
    strcpy(command2, string(this->command).substr(cmd_sep_out + 1).c_str());
  }
  strcpy(command1_print, string(this->command).substr(0, cmd_sep_out).c_str());
  if(cmd_sep_err != string::npos){
    strcpy(command2_print, string(this->command).substr(cmd_sep_err + 1).c_str());
  } else{
    strcpy(command2_print, string(this->command).substr(cmd_sep_out + 1).c_str());
  }

  int args_count1 = _parseCommandLine(command1, args1);
  int args_count2 = _parseCommandLine(command2, args2);

  if (_isBackgroundComamnd(command1)){
    _removeBackgroundSign(command1);
  }
  bool is_bg = false;
  if (_isBackgroundComamnd(command2)){
    _removeBackgroundSign(command2);
    is_bg = true;
  }
  SmallShell& smash = SmallShell::getInstance();
  int smash_pid = getpid();

  int first_fork = fork();
  if(first_fork == -1){
    perror("smash error: fork failed");
    _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
    _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
    free(command1_print);
    free(command2_print);
  }

  if(first_fork == 0){
    if(this->getIsPipe()){
      setpgrp();
    }
    int fd[2];
    if(pipe(fd) == -1){
      perror("smash error: pipe failed");
      _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
      _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
      free(command1_print);
      free(command2_print);
    }
    int second_fork = fork();
    if(second_fork == -1){
      perror("smash error: fork failed");
      _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
      _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
      free(command1_print);
      free(command2_print);
    }
    else if(second_fork == 0){
      setpgrp();
      if(cmd_sep_err != string::npos){
        dup2(fd[1], STDERR_FILENO);
      } else{
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
      }
      close(fd[1]);
      close(fd[0]);

      Command* command_obj1 = smash.CreateCommand(command1);

      if(strcmp(args1[0], "showpid") == 0){
        std::cout << "smash pid is " << smash_pid << std::endl;
      } else{
        command_obj1->execute();
      }
      _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
      _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
      free(command1_print);
      free(command2_print);
      delete command_obj1;
      smash.setQuitShell(true);
      return;
    }
    int third_fork = fork();
    if(third_fork == -1){
      perror("smash error: fork failed");
      _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
      _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
      free(command1_print);
      free(command2_print);
    } else if(third_fork == 0){
       setpgrp();
       dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
       close(fd[1]);
       close(fd[0]);

       Command* command_obj2 = smash.CreateCommand(command2);
       if(strcmp(args2[0], "showpid") == 0){
        std::cout << "smash pid is " << smash_pid << std::endl;
      } else{
        command_obj2->execute();
      }
      _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
      _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
      free(command1_print);
      free(command2_print);
      delete command_obj2;
      smash.setQuitShell(true);
      return;
    }
    close(fd[1]);
    close(fd[0]);
    waitpid(first_fork, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(second_fork, NULL, 0);
    _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
    _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
    smash.setQuitShell(true);
    return;
  } else{
    this->pid = first_fork;
    if(is_bg){
      smash.getJobs()->addJob(this->command, this->pid, command2_print, false, -1, is_bg);
    } else{
      smash.setForeGroundPID(this->pid);
      smash.setForegroundJID(-1);
      smash.setForegroundCommand(this->command);

      waitpid(this->pid, NULL, WUNTRACED);
      smash.setForeGroundPID(-1);
    }
  }
  _clear_command(command1, args1, args_count1);
  _clear_command(command2, args2, args_count2);
  free(command1_print);
  free(command2_print);
}
```

EDIT:
Assuming I have a file called `file` with the content:

```
a
b
c
```

When executing my terminal and typing `cat file | less`
I expect the output:

```
a
b
c
```

But instead of getting this output just one time, I get

```
a
b
c
```

Over and over again until my machine crashes

Comment: @YSC probably the right terminology would be just a pipe but I was meaning to commands like this one `cat file | less`

Comment: The creation of a pipe probably.
This is probably not that practical but this is a part of an academic assignment.

Comment: Edited my question to mention it all :)